# tp-link CPE210 Network - relatively long range - access points

Tags: routing, access-point

I want to establish a wifi connection for a farm. So there is the main house which has internet access. A Barn(300ft) and an other hall(500ft) should have their own networks. It is in an open area. No trees should block the view. My planned setup is a router in the main house with an http://www.tp-link.com/resources/document/CPE210_V1_Datasheet.pdf TP-LINK CPE210 mounted at the outside. The barn and the hall each get one too and then their own access points. So my question is if that make sense and could work. I have experinece in setting up networks, but not so much in "long" distance networking. I also took a look at "Ubiquiti NanoStation locoM2". Are my thoughts going in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful when editing your question. For example: how the network will be used (types of traffic, how much, etc), number of devices in each location, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it should be working, you just need do assign subnet on each network example house 192.168.0.1/24 barn 192.168.1.0/24 hall 192.168.2.0/24 and do not forget to do static routing on each wireless router so it can connected each other.